# Django Rest Framework - how to pass kwargs to model.save()?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have overridden the .save() method of one of my models to use an extra argument. My question is: how I can pass this argument through the serializer.save(). My code below:

```
class DeliveryCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.none()
    serializer_class = DeliverySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoModelPermissions, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(permissions=(self.request.user,) ) #here, how to I do it?
```

In a normal view I do it like this: `self.object.save(owner=self.request.user)`

I have tried: `serializer.save(permissions=(self.request.user,),owner=self.request.user )`  and it does not work

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please add code for your model and serializer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) `serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)` should be enough. The keyword arguments will be included in the validated_data argument when `.create()` or `.update()` are called on the serializer. It would help if you posted the traceback you're getting and your model/serializer code as Rahul Gupta suggested.

Comment: OK, but then I have to override the .create() in the form class. I had to stop working int his project, but as soon as I come back to it I will do it and rate the answer. Thanks!